Traversing two dimensional arrays in C
I am trying to write a program that reads in a matrix from a file and stores the matrix in a two dimensional array. It seems that the file is opening successfully and the program is reading the correct data. However, when I print out the contents of the 2d array later, it is incorrect even though I have not altered the array.
here is my program:
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    
    char key_file_name[20];
    char plaintext_file_name[20];
    FILE *key_ptr = NULL;
    FILE *plaintext_ptr = NULL;
    int matrix_size;
    int matrix[matrix_size][matrix_size];

    printf("key file: ");
    scanf("%s" , key_file_name);
    printf("plaintext file name: ");
    scanf("%s" , plaintext_file_name);
    
    key_ptr = fopen(key_file_name , "r");
    
    fscanf(key_ptr , "%d" , &matrix_size);
    printf("matrix size: %d\n" , matrix_size);
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < matrix_size ; ++i){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < matrix_size ; ++j){
            fscanf(key_ptr , "%d" , &matrix[i][j]);
            printf("%d" , matrix[i][j]);
        }
        
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    fclose(key_ptr);
      
    printf("matrix size: %d\n"
            "%d%d\n"
            "%d%d\n" ,
            matrix_size ,
            matrix[0][0] , matrix[0][1] ,
            matrix[1][0] , matrix[1][1]);

    return 0;
}

here is the k1.txt file:
2
2   4
3   5

here is the output:
key file: k1.txt
plaintext file name: p1.txt
matrix size: 2
24
35
matrix size: 2
35
35


I tried typing the code you see above. I expected the output to be:
key file: k1.txt
plaintext file name: p1.txt
matrix size: 2
24
35
matrix size: 2
24
35



int matrix_size; int matrix[matrix_size][matrix_size]; --> undefined behavior. matrix_size has indeterminate value and is used to declare a variable length array.

You need to move the declaration of matrix down, after you read matrix_size from the file.

You need to set matrix_size before using it to declare a variable-length array, for obvious reasons.

Thank you, that makes total sense. Also it fixed the problem.

Change "%d%d\n" into "%d %d\n" for printf. Otherwise 2 4 prints as 24
